# Calling a function inside react render

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have this line

```
<td>{device.ID}</td>
```

and I want to display the type of device based on the ID number, so that I can call function

I tried below approach by reading this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50195988/calling-arrow-function-inside-react-render)

```
<td>{getDeviceId(device.ID)}</td> /// Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","
```

Any Idea of what's I am missing there?

Comment: You need to provide the entire code that's related to the question, including how you're rendering the view and how you're defining the new function you mentioned. It should probably be included how it's defined within the class its represented in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.getDeviceId(device.ID)` or `this.props.getDeviceId(device.ID)`